# How to create a service in corda to store arbitrary data in some arbitrary place in the node database and not inside the vault

Tags: java, h2, corda

I want to do a spring-like service with a repository and everything in corda, in order to store some intermediate date just in the node database not in the vault

i saw that i should use @cordaService not just @service but i am having problems with where do i put it, in the client or the flows or wherever else.

here is a screenshot of the [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6TTr.png)

at the end i want to be able to have something like that here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/corda-api") // The paths for HTTP requests are relative to this base path
public class Controller {
private final CordaRPCOps proxy;
@PostMapping
public Order addOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
return orderService.save(order);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store stuff in a service in corda then, as you mentioned, you need to use a `@CordaService` class. See https://lankydan.dev/2018/08/19/corda-services-101 or https://docs.corda.net/api-service-classes.html for more information.

This will then be accessed by a flow that simply gets the value from the service and returns it. The client can then make use of the returned value.

Comment: aha ok, do i need to create a repo somewhere here as in spring ? or it is automatically created ? 

could you  elaborate a liitle a bit here and give a me a complete example here for persisting something in the database? iam a bit confused still

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part. You can use `ServiceHub.jdbcSession` or `ServiceHub.withEntityManager` (see these docs - https://docs.corda.net/head/api-persistence.html#jdbc-session)

Comment: aha i see, thanks. I did that in a separate service class. Do you know how can i call it from the @RestController i put above ? I mean how to retrieve the service class in the controller class? I want persist to be called in a post method.

Comment: to access a corda service from outside of the node is not currently possible. To achieve this, you need to write a flow that delegates to the service and calls the required function.